# algorithm for Link between different view of Dicom images

Tags: matlab, dicom, dcmtk

I am working in matlab for view Dicom images from the pacs . Now I have three different series of dicom image for same patient which i download from Pacs. first one is **Axial** plane view , second one is **sagittal** plane view , third one is **coronal** plane view. Now i want to Link between above Series

For example,
          if I am clicking the Axial image then i want to refer with other views where the point of the Axial image place in sagittal view and coronal view.

By googling I got some Points that **Image Position , Image Orientation** and  **Slice Location** tags are used for that Reference link between that Series.But I am not get it that calculation how to do?

Let us assume input of above tags for single image with respective series ,

**1. Axial View:**

- Image Position = (-118.444 \ -168.443 \ -46.0727)
- Image Orientation = (0.996206 \ -0.0224615 \ -0.0840777 \ -0.0083926 \ 0.936831 \ -0.349683)
- Slice Location =-95.85758972

**2. Sagittal View:**

- Image Position = (-63.5956 \ -159.015 \ 60.7561)
- Image Orientation = (0.0188908 \ 0.999809 \ -0.00509657 \ -0.0341498 \ -0.00445565 \ -0.999407 )
- Slice Location =65.27085876

**3. Coronal View:**

- Image Position = (-100.457 \ -102.583 \ 72.264)
- Image Orientation = (0.999514 \ -0.00466935 \ -0.0308238 \ -0.0311593 \ -0.16129 \ -0.986415)
- Slice Location =119.9748077

and above three view Pixel Data Size is (512 X 512) .

Now  how I calculate the Reference Line and Point from above Value  ? If any other Tag value need then i will ready to provide that Tag.

Comment: Is it necessary that you code this yourself? Could you just use a program like 3Dslicer?

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct data. http://www.dclunie.com/medical-image-faq/html/part2.html#DICOMLocalizers is a great reference for this type of operation.

It is also explained in section C.7.6.2.1 of the DICOM standard, Part 3 (http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/pdf/part03.pdf)